# How run grunt when server start from node?

Tags: javascript, node.js, gruntjs

I would like to refresh automatically my generated files, generated by grunt. To do so, I would like to run automatically grant from nodeJs.

I found the reverse, run node server from grunt, but it's not what I want to do.

Do you have tips to run grunt when the server start? Maybe it's something like call command line from node, but I'm not used to do that. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Final solution:

```
    var spawn = require('child_process').spawn;
    var cp = spawn(process.env.comspec, ['/c', 'grunt']);// ['/c', 'command', '-arg1', '-arg2']

    cp.stdout.on("data", function(data) {
        console.log(data.toString());
    });

    cp.stderr.on("data", function(data) {
        console.error(data.toString());
    });
```

Found here: [Spawn on Node JS (Windows Server 2012)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18334181/spawn-on-node-js-windows-server-2012)
Thanks to @Diadara.

Answer (score 1):

You could use child process

```
var spawn = require('child_process').spawn,
grunt    = spawn('grunt', ['args']);

grunt.stdout.on('data', function (data) {
console.log('stdout: ' + data);
});
```

As you can see the child process is run asynchronously, if you want to run grunt synchronously then look at this question [node.js execute system command synchronously](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4443597/node-js-execute-system-command-synchronously)

Comment: Yes, but I try before ;) And I have some trouble under windows OS. https://github.com/joyent/node/issues/2318 or https://www.google.dk/search?q=spawn+enoent&oq=spawn+enoent&aqs=chrome..69i57.3004j0j1&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#q=spawn+enoent+windows&safe=off

Comment: Your solution is OK under !windows (mac & linux work)